# For loop over a list of lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm new to Python and I have a question about for loops over lists of lists.

If I have a number of lists, and I want to change each one into an enumerated dictionary, can I do that within a loop?

Here's what I've tried, and it doesn't work.

```
master_list = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6, list7, list8 ...]


for list in master_list:
    dict(enumerate(list))
```

Comment: Why do you need them to be a dict? If you are enumerating, the effect is almost the same as having a a list of values but using way more memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a new list of dictionaries with a small list comprehension:

```
master_list = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]

list_o_dicts = [dict(enumerate(l)) for l in master_list ]
print(list_o_dicts)
# [{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}, {0: 'd', 1: 'e', 2: 'f'}]
```

If you want this to replace your current list, you can just assign it back. If you want to change the list in place, then you'll need to make a loop and actually assign the dict to the list element — for example:

```
for i, l in enumerate(master_list):
    master_list[i] = dict(enumerate(l))
```